# The most efficient way to check dir for temp files and skip dir if found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This script makes a list of the top level directories in the current direcory, then checks if the directory is in use by attempting to rename it. I needs to check the resulting dirs not used if there are temp filetypes like `*.!qB`, `*.part` or `*.dash*` so these incomplete directories can be skipped, leaving the rest for further processing.

```
reldir = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(f)]
for d in reldir:
    try:
        os.rename(d, os.path.join(d + '_'))
    except PermissionError:
        continue
    os.rename(os.path.join(d + '_'), d)
    os.chdir(d)
    print(os.getcwd())
    # is this really the simplest way?
    files = glob.glob('.' + '/**/*.*', recursive=True)
    # check for temp files here
    print(files)
    # finally go back to root
    os.chdir(indir)
```

I'm not sure it needs to be this complicated. I have the desired code for the temp file check in `batch` form.

```
dir *.!qb *.part *.dash* /s /b && goto done
```

I'm looking for the simplest, most efficient way here, like the `batch` above. Also any optimization for the rest of the code is very much appreciated.

edit:

just to clarify, these two lines are what I need help with:

```
    files = glob.glob('.' + '/**/*.*', recursive=True)
    # check for temp files here
```

The first line builds a list of ALL files (probably unnecessary), and the exclusion line (the missing second line) is where I would need a way to find the mentioned temp files, in a way that doesn't stop the script but instead continues to the next iteration.

Comment: Hi, not sure why you use `os.path.join` with a single argument, you don't need it. also, you don't need to `chdir` at all, just use your glob with d instead of '.'

Comment: I can't get it to work with `'d'` instead of `'.'`, a printout of `files` changes to empty brackets. Not sure what you mean by `os.path.join` using only a single argument.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need help with and pare down your code to just the problem parts. See [ask]. If you want general advice, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably the better place to ask. As well, I don't know the syntax for Windows globs, so it would help if you explained what they do exactly.

Comment: @wjandrea I added clarification to the question

Comment: @Bricktop Amir is saying to use the variable `d`, not the string `'d'`. `os.path.join(d + '_')` gives a single argument to `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do a recursive glob for each of the patterns and `continue` if any matches exist.

```
patterns = ['*.!qb', '*.part', '*.dash*']
for d in reldir:
    # ...
    g = (glob.glob(os.path.join('**', p), recursive=True) for p in patterns)
    if any(g):
        continue
```

Though like Amir mentioned in the comments, you don't need to change directories, just put `d` in the glob:

```
    g = [glob.glob(os.path.join(d, '**', p) ...
```

Comment: I get error `TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given`

Comment: Um, where do I put the further processing for the completed directories where no temp files were found?

Comment: After the if block

Comment: I tried `print(d + "seems complete")` after the if block and I get a list of nothing at all, even though there are many directories not in use and without temp files.